# Цель _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal сильно тормозит сборку

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
1>Итоги по целям:


1>        0 мс вызовов   1 GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute 

...     
1>        4 мс вызовов   1 CompileLicxFiles                        
1>        8 мс вызовов   1 CreateManifestResourceNames             
1>        9 мс вызовов   1 IncrementalClean                        
1>       23 мс вызовов   1 ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades       
1>       25 мс вызовов   1 FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences    
1>       27 мс вызовов   1 _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites      
1>      128 мс вызовов   1 ResolveAssemblyReferences               
1>     2773 мс вызовов   1 CoreResGen                              
1>     7386 мс вызовов   1 CoreCompile                             
1>    19162 мс вызовов   1 CopyFilesToOutputDirectory              
1>    172775 мс вызовов   1 _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal

1>Сборка успешно завершена.
1>    Предупреждений: 0
1>    Ошибок: 0
1>
1>Прошло времени 00:03:22.35
```

Как видно, последние две цели занимают очень много времени. Что это за цели и можно их как-то отключить без вреда для программы? Такая долгая компиляция происходит только после внесения каких-либо изменений, если же компилировать несколько раз подряд, то это занимает доли секунды.

Comment: Можно взять полный лог и посмотреть, чем же там занимался _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal. Но судя по названию - у вас в проекте есть файлы, у которых установлен признак копирования в папку проекта и файлов много и\или меняются часто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, пишу то, что помогло. Всё это время проект лежал у меня на флешке, откуда он и запускался. После того, как я перенёс его на SSD диск, компиляция после внесения изменений стала занимать не более секунды, а без изменений - мгновенно. Вывод: на флешке хранить проект нежелательно.